# Plotting 2-dim array as line plot python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a sorted lits [(1,5) (2,4) (3,5)] and I want to make a plot that plots the value 1 from x=0 to 5, the value 2 from 5 to 9 and the value 3 from 9 to 14. Any suggestions of how I can do this in python?

Comment: I could probably help you, but I have no idea what you're really asking or how the three seashells, I mean tuples, relate to it.

Comment: Highly unclear question. No idea what are your y-values. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you want `print( *[t[0] for t in [(1,5),(2,4),(3,5)] for _ in range(t[1])] )`

Answer (score 0):

Note that `0` is not in your data. So you need to add one tuple giving the value for `x=0`. After doing that you can plot the y values as function of the cumulative x values.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = [(1,0), (1,5), (2,4), (3,5)]
y,x = zip(*l)
plt.step(np.cumsum(x),y)
plt.show()
```

[image]